How to make the provider rebuild only one widget
In my Flutter application I have a form with various TextFormFields, each with a microphone to transcribe what is said.
I implemented it with SpeechToTextProvider.
When I push a microphone, it writes to the right input, however all microphones activate and the setState updates all inputs and not just the one selected by the user.
How can I ensure that only one microphone is selected and rebuilt at a time?
Thanks to anyone who can help me!
This is the initialization of the the speechProvider in the root:
final SpeechToText speech = SpeechToText();
  late SpeechToTextProvider speechProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    speechProvider = SpeechToTextProvider(speech);
    initSpeechState();
  }

  Future<void> initSpeechState() async {
    await speechProvider.initialize();
  }

Then I add the the ChangeNotifierProvider in the root widget:
ChangeNotifierProvider<SpeechToTextProvider>.value(value: speechProvider),

This is the form:
class DayForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const DayForm({required this.days, super.key});

  final Map<int, Day> days;

  @override
  State<DayForm> createState() => _DayFormState();
}

class _DayFormState extends State<DayForm> {
  Map<int, Day> get days => widget.days;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: "DayForm");

  late final Map<int, dynamic> _daysFields = {};

  void _setLastTextChange(inputKey, lastText) {
    setState(() {
      _daysFields[inputKey]["lastTextChange"] = lastText;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    for (int dayNumber = 1; dayNumber <= 7; dayNumber++) {
      _daysFields[dayNumber] = {
        "controller": TextEditingController(),
        "lastTextChange": "",
      };
    }

    days.forEach((key, value) {
      _daysFields[key]["controller"].text = value.description ?? "";
      _setLastTextChange(key, _daysFields[key]["controller"].text);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var formFields = <Widget>[];

    _daysFields.forEach((key, value) {
      formFields.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Row(
          key: UniqueKey(), // here or in Padding is the same
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: value["controller"],
                onChanged: (changed) {
                  _setLastTextChange(key, changed);
                },
              ),
            ),
            SpeechProvider(
              key: ValueKey(key),
              controller: value["controller"],
              lastInputChange: value["lastTextChange"],
              setLastInputChange: _setLastTextChange,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ));
    });

    return Consumer<ApplicationState>(
      builder: (context, appState, _) {
        return Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: formFields,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

And here is the code to call SpeechToTextProvider:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text_provider.dart';

class SpeechProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  const SpeechProvider({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.lastInputChange,
    required this.setLastInputChange,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String lastInputChange;
  final void Function(dynamic, String) setLastInputChange;

  @override
  SpeechProviderState createState() => SpeechProviderState();
}

class SpeechProviderState extends State<SpeechProvider> {
  String lastWords = '';
  late SpeechToTextProvider speechProvider;

  void startListening() {
    if (speechProvider.isAvailable && speechProvider.isNotListening) {
      lastWords = '';

      speechProvider.listen();

      speechProvider.stream.listen((event) {
        final result = event.recognitionResult;
        if (result != null) {
          resultListener(result);
        }
      });

      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void stopListening() {
    if (!mounted) return;
    if (speechProvider.isListening) {
      speechProvider.stop();
      setState(() {
        widget.setLastInputChange((widget.key as ValueKey<dynamic>).value, widget.controller.text);
      });
    }
  }

  void resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      if (result.finalResult) {
        widget.setLastInputChange((widget.key as ValueKey<dynamic>).value, widget.controller.text);
      } else {
        lastWords = result.recognizedWords;
        widget.controller.text = '${widget.lastInputChange} $lastWords';
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    speechProvider = Provider.of<SpeechToTextProvider>(context);

    return TapRegion(
      onTapOutside: (tap) => speechProvider.isListening ? stopListening() : null,
      child: SizedBox(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: speechProvider.isListening ? stopListening : startListening,
          child: Icon(speechProvider.isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_off),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you try print(inputKey) inside _setLastTextChange, what do you get?

@Dhafin Rayhan I have a random result between 1 and 7... I was convinced it would print the key of the corresponding input, in order from 1 to 7, but no. I don't understand this, I hadn't checked this value because it writes and saves in Firestore the values of the right field! Why this question? Have you noticed any other errors?

@DhafinRayhan why when I print inputKey it gives a random value, but the string is saved to the correct input? Can you give me an explanation since you asked? I can't figure it out

I actually tried to reproduce the issue with your code, but I replaced ChangeNotifierProvider with StateProvider from Riverpod (I'm more fluent with Riverpod), and it seems to me that the text from the each microphone is set accordingly... (it correctly updates the particular text field). So I guess there must be an issue with how you setup the ChangeNotifierProvider? Maybe that's a good place to start debugging with

try to manage state of each microphone independently.

any ideas on how? I tried, but without success, since they are managed by a single widget

and I pass a key to each microphone, so I thought they should be managed independently

try to give key

i already give the key...

The problem is that you provide the same instance of SpeechToTextProvider to all SpeechProvider widgets. You constructed SpeechToTextProvider in the root widget, so every widget below it that try to read it from the provider (Provider.of<SpeechToTextProvider>(context)) will get the same instance. Now when you call speechProvider.listen() from a SpeechProvider widget, the other SpeechProvider widgets are also listening to it through speechProvider.stream.listen, because all the speechProvider refer to the same object inherited by the provider. Hence why widget.setLastInputChange is called from every single SpeechProvider widget.
One possible fix is to make every SpeechProvider widget has its own SpeechToText and SpeechToTextProvider. This is done by moving the initialization of both of them (as shown in your first code snippet) from the root widget to the SpeechProvider widget.

The fix you propose is the very first thing I developed. I had made the code starting from the example provided by the plugin, but this gave problems every time I stopped recording, since when the widget was destroyed the listener was no longer there and then when I started it again it always gave errors.

I therefore made this solution with provider, which does not give any errors, but as you say the listener is unique for everyone. That it is always listening is not a problem, but is there a way to rebuild just the widget I clicked?

@GiuliaSantoiemma I believe all microphones are activated when you push one because all the individual listeners are actually listening to any event from any microphone, due to the same speechProvider instance used. Maybe you can trace back what calls the setState, and what calls that caller of it, and so on?

you are right, all microphones are activated together.
What you suggest is what I'm trying to do, but so far without success!

I guess that should be closer to the solution, though. Can you post that one instead?

unfortunately I don't have anything that works better than this, for now I'm debugging to understand, but I'm stuck here
